# React Bootstrap Modal Scroll to Top

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have React Bootstrap modal that contains a form. When the form validates, it displays the errors at the top of the form. Because the form is large, these errors are not visible.

I need the modal to scroll back to the top.

I have tried attaching a ref to the modal and using `scrollTop` but it doesn't seem to work - like this

```
<Modal ref={el => (this.modal = el)} ......... />
```

Then; `this.modal.scrollTop = 0`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scrollTop` only for the DOM element and not the React component class, To get the DOM element make use of `ReactDOM.findDOMNode()` like

```
<Modal ref={el => (this.modal = el)} ......... />

const modalDOM = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.modal);
modalDOM.scrollTop = 0
```

Comment: I used the same approach and 'ReactDOM' is not defined.